# Docker: MySQL[2002] when trying to setup 2 DB containers

Tags: mysql, docker, laravel-5, docker-compose, digital-ocean

Hi I'm trying to learn Docker.

As a starting point, I've followed DigitalOcean's setup tutorial for Laravel [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose).

I've managed to get all containers up and even finished building my Laravel app. Now I want to setup a 2nd DB for testing.

I duplicated the settings of the `db` part of `docker-compose`, and changed the container name and ports.

All containers setup fine, but whenever I try do run `docker exec` in either of the db containers, I get a 2002 error, which I did not encounter while I had only 1 DB container running:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mysql-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: todo_app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: todo_web
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: todo_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todo
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ent3r1n
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

  db_test:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: todo_db_test
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todo
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ent3r1n
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Output of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
f5ccebc57f9d        digitalocean.com/php   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   15 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       9000/tcp                                   todo_app
7cc53434d7d7        nginx:alpine           "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   15 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   todo_web
7aab5318e7af        mysql:5.7.22           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp                     todo_db_test
5b72306f63a4        mysql:5.7.22           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                     todo_db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ever got the problem like this, because of image you use: `image: mysql:5.7.22`
You should use: `image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7`. 
Hope it can help you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... this is a side project.
Anyways, managed to get it working... but figure out how to connect to todo_db_test on Sequel Pro...

Comment: I am curious that have you accessed the container?